# tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified : Causes Deployment Failure

Tags: github-actions, continuous-deployment, cicd

I've been trying to deploy my laravel application through CICD with Github Actions to Godaddy and my deployment kept on failing and I am seeing this :

drone-scp version: v1.6.14
tar all files into /tmp/zyZUEoEtCt.tar.gz
remote server os type is unix
scp file to server.
create folder ~/public_html
drone-scp error: tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
drone-scp rollback: remove all target tmp file
remove file zyZUEoEtCt.tar.gz
2024/03/16 06:12:46 tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified

here's my deploy.yml :

```
name: Deploy WCP to godaddy in feature branch

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - features/dev-godaddy # Trigger deployment on pushes to this branch

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up PHP
      uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
      with:
        php-version: '8.2' # Match the PHP version to your project requirements
        extensions: mbstring, xml, ctype, iconv, intl, pdo_mysql, gd, mysqli, curl
        ini-values: post_max_size=256M, upload_max_filesize=256M
        coverage: none

    - name: Install Composer dependencies
      run: composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader

    - name: Set up Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: '20.11.1' # Match the Node version to your project requirements
    
    - name: Install NPM dependencies
      run: npm install
    
    - name: Build Node frontend
      run: npm run dev

    - name: Deploy to GoDaddy
      uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.GODADDY_SSH_HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.GODADDY_SSH_USERNAME }}
        key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        port: 22
        source: "."
        target: "~/public_html" # Adjust this to your specific path
    
    - name: SSH commands
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.GODADDY_SSH_HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.GODADDY_SSH_USERNAME }}
        key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        port: 22
        script:
          cd ~/public_html
```

I've tried these (all didn't work):

1. Adding these lines before the Deploy to GoDaddy step in my workflow:

```
- name: Set terminal type
  run: export TERM=xterm
```

2. Adding these lines before the Deploy to GoDaddy step in my workflow:

```
- name: Set terminal type
      run: export TERM=vt100
```

3. Modified this portion:

```
- name: SSH commands
  uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
  with:
    host: ${{ secrets.GODADDY_SSH_HOST }}
    username: ${{ secrets.GODADDY_SSH_USERNAME }}
    key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    port: 22
    script: 
      export TERM=xterm
      cd ~/public_html
      # Any other post-deployment commands you might need
      # For example, clearing cache:
      # php artisan cache:clear
```

My research so far says that the issue is related to the terminal environment during the execution of the drone-scp action, which is used by the appleboy/scp-action GitHub Action being used for deployment. But everything doesn't work well with me, I should be missing something. I'll appreciate any help. Thank you.